How does a conformal transformation affect the frame bundle metric of that manifold?
Suppose I have a metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ over an n-dimensional smooth orientable Riemannian manifold $M$. We then utilize Cartans repere mobile (moving frames) to define oriented orthonormal frames $e^{a}=e_{\mu}^{a}dx^{\mu}$ everywhere, expressing the metric as $$g_{\mu\nu}=e_{\mu}^{a}e_{\nu}^{b}E_{ab}$$
Where $E_{ab}$ are the components of the Euclidean metric dimension n. Choosing a compatible Connection gives us a covariant derivative:
$$\nabla_{\mu}e^{a}=0=\partial_{\mu}e^{a}-\omega_{\mu}^{ac}e_{c}$$
We can endow the tangent space of the oriented orthonormal frame bundle $SO(M)$ with a bundle metric:
$$g_{AB}=g_{\mu\nu}+k(\omega,\omega)$$
The latter term corresponds to a metric on the tangent space of $SO(n)$. We note that this splitting (into vertical and horizontal components) is everywhere well defined by our choice of connection (i.e. the tangent bundle $TSO(M)$ splits as a Whitney sum)
Now suppose the base space $M$ is conformally transformed $g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow\sigma^{2}g_{\mu\nu}$ by a smooth function $\sigma$ on M.
How then does our bundle metric transform?
Specifically how does $k(\omega,\omega)$ transform? I've tried a few things. I know that the connection can be split into  two parts one involving first order derivatives of $\sigma$ and another term is the connection with no conformal transformation. I suspect that, aside from the extra terms from derivatives of $\sigma$ that $k(\omega,\omega)$ is also conformally transformed, but differently from $g_{\mu\nu}$? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
NOTE: I've chosen a compact group for this principal fiber bundle such that we can endow the group with a bi-invariant metric (however that need not be the case in general).
Another way of asking this is: is there a canonical construction for the metric on the structure group of the frame bundle (and reductions to G structures such as above) from the elements of the base manifold ?
I Should note that the connections I've chosen were COMPATIBLE (i.e. torsionless)

The metric on the vertical part of the frame bundle won't change, what's changing is the splitting into horizontal and vertical: indeed, the notion of "horizontal" on the frame bundle is by definition equivalent to choosing a principal connection, which is in turn the same as choosing an affine connection on $TM$ (this comes from the general theory of connections on principal bundles, see e.g. the book of Kobayashi-Nomizu). You need to understand how your connection is changing when you conformally change the metric.

@RamiroLafuente I know I can regard a "spin" connection as above $\omega^{ab}=\omega^{ab} \mu dx^{\mu} $  as an $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ valued basis on $SO(n)$   And we can define an inner product between two such basis using $E{ab}$ and $g_{\mu\nu}$ and their inverses to raise and lower indices.   Then we have that $\omega^{ab} {\mu } \omega{ab} ^{\mu}$  transforms porportionally to $g^{\mu\nu}$ and hence as $1/\sigma ^2$  or inversely compared to the base metric.  is there something wrong here?

@RamiroLafuente  I Have K&N but it's been a while I'll dig into them.

@RamiroLafuente   I do get that the conformally transformed connection looks like $\tilde{\omega} = \omega +\Omega$ where $\omega$ is the connection on the conformally unchanged metric and the latter term involves derivatives of $\sigma$.
